# PostgreSQL & Liquibase - default id value from sequence

Tags: database, postgresql, liquibase

I generated a **changelog.xml** from an existent database using Liquibase.

- Liquibase 4.9.1
- PostgreSQL 13.2

The original database was built using the below commands. One **company table** that has its primary key **id** defaulted to the **my_company_id_seq sequence** nextval

The Liquibase **generate-changelog** command created two change sets (company table & sequence) but the configured company default id, that used to point to the my_company_id_seq sequence, was lost, now it uses **GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY**.

I understand GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY is the recommended approach from PostgreSQl 10+ on instead of SERIAL, but not for my use case where sometimes I need to generate the ID in advance (calling nextValue from the sequence) and later pass it at time to insert the data into company table, and other times I can just let the id to be generated by the configured *DEFAULT nextval('my_company_id_seq')*

Do you know the rationale of it?

Or maybe there is no and it can be considered  a bug?

Any insights and/or suggestions will be really appreciated

**DDL from existent database:**

```
CREATE SEQUENCE my_company_id_seq
INCREMENT BY 1
START WITH 1;

CREATE TABLE company (
    id INT NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('my_company_id_seq') PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR NOT NULL
);
```

**changelog.xml generated from existent database:**

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext" xmlns:pro="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro/liquibase-pro-4.6.xsd http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-4.6.xsd">

    <changeSet author="liquibase (generated)" id="1656837328215-1">
        <createTable tableName="company">
            <column autoIncrement="true" name="id" type="INTEGER">
                <constraints nullable="false" primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="company_pkey"/>
            </column>
            <column name="name" type="VARCHAR">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>

    <changeSet author="liquibase (generated)" id="1656837328215-2">
        <createSequence cacheSize="1" cycle="false" dataType="bigint" incrementBy="1" maxValue="9223372036854775807" minValue="1" sequenceName="my_company_id_seq" startValue="1"/>
    </changeSet>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

**Generated sequence & table from Liquibase changelog:**

```
CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS app.my_company_id_seq
    INCREMENT 1
    START 1
    MINVALUE 1
    MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
    CACHE 1;    

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS app.company
(
    id integer NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 1 ),
    name character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT company_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Comment: `pg_get_serial_sequence('company', id')`

Comment: Could you explain what you meant by that ?

Comment: You can still find sequence that  is behind `IDENTITY` using `pg_get_serial_sequence` function. And you can still get values from this sequence.

Comment: ok, I got your point, but I'm not looking for the sequence behind it. I want to understand why Liquibase behaves like that and assumes it as the best approach by default instead of keeping the original relationship